# Undo bootstrap media statement without editing bootstrap file?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

Anyway that I can retract this in a subsequent stylesheet without having to remove it from bootstrap-responsive. I don't like making changes to the bootstrap sheet directly.

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
    body {
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WHOOPS I had a missing brace when I tried this but it works!

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    body {
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
}
```